How to refer to a file path in android?
I'm beginner in android. It may be a basic knowledge for android developers. But I haven't found solution on the Internet.
I have a onnx file, I want to run it on android system. In the beginning I put it in the res directory (as onnxruntime example shows) and try to read it by readBytes(), but the process was out of memory and crashed. I saw a solution for this issue is to create session directly using the file path, rather than reading it in the memory. So now I need to put the onnx file somewhere and refer to it by it's path. But I don't know where to put the file and what is the path to this file. I tried to put it in assets, but I don't want to open it. I just need the path.
val sessionOptions: OrtSession.SessionOptions = OrtSession.SessionOptions()
sessionOptions.registerCustomOpLibrary(OrtxPackage.getLibraryPath())
ortSession = ortEnv.createSession("l1_decoder.onnx",sessionOptions)

I need the file path in createSession.

You can put your onnx file(s) inside a folder you created inside the assets folder like so:
String[] paths = getAssets().path("YOUR_ONNX_FOLDER_NAME"); //if inside an activity
for(String path : paths) {
   //detect if path contains the onnx file you want
   if(path.contains("your_file_name.onnx")) {
      //your code here
   }       
}

